# xcode iOS App Crashes after the renaming of view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

[Outlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuqyg.png) [Crash at Entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xHid.png)  Crash Image Screenshot

[image: Crash Image Screenshot[1]]

I am getting an crash after I renamed my View Controller . Swift file to CalculatorViewController.swift
I also tried refactoring new class name to be mirrored across all ports of entry to the app. I am getting Abort Signal Error. Please do help with this one! This is my error
UPDATE: ERROR IN queue com.apple.mainthread (serial) Thread 1

Crash point in code

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

UPDATE.

> 2019-03-11 15:36:01.990755+0530 NDv2[4619:144763] Unknown class
>   CalculatorViewController in Interface Builder file. 2019-03-11
>   15:36:02.040903+0530 NDv2[4619:144763] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
>   '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TextOutput.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef3e1bb **exceptionPreprocess + 331  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010cf58735 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010ef3dd29 -[NSException raise] + 9   3   Foundation
>
>   0x000000010c983de4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] +
>   292   4   UIKitCore                           0x00000001113a3292
>   -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87     5   UIKitCore                           0x000000011163a573 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109   6
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef29cfd -[NSArray
>   makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317    7   UIKitCore
>
>   0x00000001116372b9 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1814  8
>
>   UIKitCore                           0x00000001113aa452
>   -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383   9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001113aaddc -[UIViewController loadView] + 177   10  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00000001113ab0ee -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 175   11 
>   UIKitCore                           0x00000001113ab940
>   -[UIViewController view] + 27     12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111a02c53 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] +
>   122   13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111a0336e
>   -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294  14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000111a165c0 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42   15  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00000001119c3833 -[UIApplication
>   _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4595   16  UIKitCore                           0x00000001119c8c2f
>   -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1623   17  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111e74e9
>   __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 866     18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111f029c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153    19  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111e7126
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 233     20  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111e7ae0
>   -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1085     21  UIKitCore
>
>   0x00000001111e5cb5 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas
>   _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 795     22  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111e595f -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 435     23  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111eaa90
>   __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 584     24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111eb80e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100   25  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111ea7ef -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]
>   + 221     26  UIKitCore                           0x00000001111ef93a -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392     27  UIKitCore                           0x00000001119c744e
>   -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515     28 
>   UIKitCore                           0x000000011156bd09
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 357   29 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011a0fc2da -[FBSSceneImpl
>   _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011a107443
>   __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 271     31 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011a106b3a
>   __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011047e602
>   _dispatch_client_callout + 8  33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110481b78 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 301  34 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011a13bba8
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 30     35  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011a13b860
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457  36  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011a13be40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eea3721
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eea2f93
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243   39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee9d63f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263    40  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010ee9ce11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625     41  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000011713b1dd GSEventRunModal + 62   42  UIKitCore
>   0x00000001119ca81d UIApplicationMain + 140    43  NDv2
>   0x000000010c6291c7 main + 71  44  libdyld.dylib
>   0x00000001104f4575 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: You’re getting this error because your viewController has an undeclared class in storyboard. Did you also rename the class in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I did change the class from ViewController in Main Storyboard!

Comment: not enough information attach outlets information top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]There is two ways to change the name of ViewController:

1) 
Ex.: class LoginViewController: UIViewController - just select the "LoginViewController", then right click -> Refactor -> Rename

This will change the name file name, class name and take care of the storyboard class name.

2) If you not able to use Method 1, then manually rename the file Name(.swift), then you have to go to the storyboard and replace the class name of the view controller. You may have issues with the outlets.

3) After that close the Xcode and then again start your project.

Comment: Indeed, I did the before. I m getting an SIGABRT message, and shows it crashes at 20 Main point and crashes with that signal

Comment: Solve the problem by clean the project and rebuild.

For clean the project go to MenuBar: Product -> Clean

Then to rebuild just click Run button as usual

Comment: Can you let me know the exact process which you're doing so that can tell you exact solution.

Comment: built View.StoryBoard, then added another file supporting called the Model or AppEngine.swift file. Worked like a charm back then, now I'm getting an error as soon as I changed the ViewController file to CalculatorVIewController. Not working even if I reverse it

Comment: Did you change the name in class as well :  class CalculatorViewController : UIViewController{}

Comment: yeah, to (newviewcontroller)

Comment: and what about Storyboard Id?

Comment: No, could you please tell me how to?

Comment: now see in image and assign storyboard Id as well same name as your class name .

Comment: I had updated with more screenshots, appreciate you could help me out. This bug is really messing me

Answer (score 0):

You have a textField or textView Or UILabel in your controller in storyboard,

1- Open your Storyboard

2- click  the UIViewController(ViewController with new name of class you have changed)

3- remove outlet with name  `TextOutput`

4- ReConnet if you want and you are ready to go

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase the 2nd point, click the controller?

Comment: UIViewController who's class name you have changed

Comment: I changed the viewcontroller.swift Then changed the filename, classname and later on Mail.Storyboard file too. It is not running. Even if I reverse the file to ViewController again, it crashes

Comment: if you want to solve the problem just try like i have said or place the project online show that i can see in to it whats the matter

Comment: Okey, but how to do it here? I'm new to this community, please bear with me.

Comment: upload it on dropbox and share link in comment

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you had an IBOutlet on your storyboard that doesn't exist any more on the class where it was defined, this can be because you manually changed the name of a property on your class or deleted it.

On your storyboard, select the initial view controller and check if there is a reference to an IBOutlet named **TextOutput**. Delete that reference and link the View again. That should fix it

Comment: Hello, I've updated Outlets collection screenshot. I think all of these are correct

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by setting the 'module' for 'Custom class' in Identity inspector